# How to find out how many bits are set (equal 1) in the product of two integers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm solution to find out how many bits are set (equal 1)  if I multiply two integers. I have numbers A and B, between 0 and MAX_INT, to eliminate the negative numbers. How do I find out how many bits will be set in the product C = A * B.

-of course calculating C and counting the bits is not the correct solution, it won't work for high values

-I work in C and C++, but it is a rather general algorithm problem. I must solve it without any math/boost library help.

Tried finding a general solution to know the bit count, but what I guessed only worked for quite some examples, it entirely failed with high numbers.

Comment: Well ... if A is a power of 2, `numberofsetbits(A * B /*no overflow, no wrapping*/) == numberofsetbits(B)` :)

Comment: Use `long long` to calculate `C`.

Comment: *"of course calculating C and counting the bits is not the correct solution"*... but there is no **other** solution, but to calculate C to know what its bits are. Or what do you think?! that if you multiply 2 numbers with 4 bits set you will get 8 bits set? 6 bits set?

Comment: You can calculate `C` in *parts* though. you need not store the entire result in memory.

Comment: Why shouldn´t bit counting work für higher numbers?
if you have a 64 bit integer, then you have 64 bits which can be possible 1 and possible numbers up to  1.8446744e+19 (or positive or negative). Checking for all bits set on a 64 bit integer will need  ~100 - 200 cycles,

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Not necessarily true, because you don't need to know the value of each individual bit. You only need to know how many 1:s there are.

Comment: "it won't work for high values" Why? The result can only have up to twice the length of your values `A` and `B`. Counting bits is no magic. There are libraries availebl for calculating with large numbers .

Comment: @klutt exactly... and to know that you need to calculate each individual bit :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala For instance, if either of A or B is zero, then C will have zero set bits. We also know that if A contains exactly one set bit, then C will have the same number of set bits as B.

Comment: You could quite easily write a function `void mul(unsigned A, unsigned B, char *C)` that stores the result of A*B as a binary number represented by a string. Then you just count the number of ones.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It starts to be a problem when both A and B have two or more set bits, but I'm definitely not sure that it does not exist a method that doesn't require you to calculate each individual bit. I might add that I'm not sure of the opposite either.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "I can't think of another way to calculate this than the obvious and correct way" is not proof for "there is no other solution". For example, I can tell you whether the product is divisble by 3 (or any other prime) without calculating the product, so how can you be sure that there is no way to figure out the number of set bits without performing the multiplication?

Comment: Since this obviously is a homework problem, you should provide the exact instructions. Not your interpretation. Also, you're expected to provide your own attempt. Please read [ask]

Comment: You might have better luck on the mathematics site: I conject there is a pattern (and can probably prove such a pattern exists) only I don't know what it is. My starting point would be to look at discrete Fourier transforms in a radix of 2.

Comment: @Bathsheba I bet there are way more numbers to multiply when you're dealing with Fourier transforms...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Indeed. The Fourier analysis would be part of the derivation of a possibly trivial formula. You'd use the latter in the implementation.

Comment: @klutt it was an interview question in a hiring test over codility, that I had to do about 2 weeks ago. Didn't save the exact description, it is indeed what I remember when it comes to details, but it was A * B which should work with A and B up to 10 million or something like this. I already mentioned it is an algorithm problem, don't use predefined specialised libraries or long long and count the bits.

Comment: @Mihnea I'm a bit picky now, but you did not say that using longer types were not allowed. You only stated that it "of course" is not a correct solution. That's something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

The question asks for an algorithm. The problem can be solved without holding a complete product, by computing each bit at a time, starting with bit 0.

Bit `C0` is found from the product of `A0 * B0` and is either `0` or `1`.

Bit `C1` is found from the sum of the products `A0 * B1 + A1 * B0` and remembering any carry.

Bit `C2` is found from the sum of `carry + A0 * B2 + A1 * B1 + A2 * B0` and so on.

As you go, you sum the single product bits, which gives the required answer: number of set bits.

Comment: I believe this is an algorithm for multiplication.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje the question asks about a product, which is a multiplication. But multiplication itself can be avoided here because the "partial product bit" is `1` only if both source bits are set. And the product itseff need not be stored, which is one of the OP's problems.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje the problem does not state "no multiplication". It just says computignthe product loses the high bits, and this algorithm does not.

Comment: The algorithm given is for binary multiplication. A much faster and easier solution would be to use 64 bits and use the CPU for multiplication.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje and then how do you solve 64 bits * 64 bits? Anyway, the question is tagged `C`.

Comment: use a BigInt library or create one on your own. I would not multiply bitwise.

Comment: do 32 bit multiplications and have 32-bit carry...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no general solution to your problem that would be simpler than performing the multiplication and counting the bits in the result. If the numbers are really large, the multiplication can be performed in slices at a significant cost in execution time.

There are however some special cases you might find useful:

- if either A or B has exactly 0 bits set (A == 0 or B == 0), then C will have 0 bits set (C == 0), and this is the only way for C to have 0 bits set.
- if either A or B has exactly 1 bit set (A or B is a power of 2), then C will have the same number of bits set as the other number. Furthermore, for C to have exactly 1 bit set, both A and B must be powers of 2.
- the number of bits set in C is less than the sum of the numbers of significant bits in A and B.
- the number of unset least significant bits in C is the sum of the number of unset least significant bits in A plus the number of unset least significant bits in C.

Comment: "that would be simpler than performing the multiplication and counting the bits in the result" - yes I quite agree. Have an upvote.

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple general solution for this.

e.g. see the following multiplication

```
3(0b0011) * 4(0b0100) = 12(0b1100)
3(0b0011) * 5(0b0101) = 15(0b1111)
3(0b0011) * 6(0b0110) = 18(0b10010)
```

The reason is that there may be some carry bits in the multiplication which will ripple through the output and change the number of ones in unpredictable ways.

You need to do the multiplication, and then count the bits.

Since `A` * `B` are `MAX_INT` (usually 31 bits), you need a 64 bit number. You can use `uint64_t`

Comment: Stating that there is no general solution is a pretty bold statement. Can you back it up? Just because you cannot see a pattern it does not mean that there is no pattern.

Comment: Actually I believe there is a pattern: this is related to convolution and whole number mathematics.

Comment: You may well find that the solution is in fact simple. I don't know for sure. Do you?

Comment: I have not found the solution until now. Please enlighten me if you find a simple solution,

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I don't know if there is an easier solution, but just the fact that you have not found one is not good enough to state that they don't exist in an answer.